# Adding two separate trend lines for specific time period in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Blockquote

Hi,
I'm trying to draw two separate trend lines for specific time periods (date), but no succeed. Could someone please advise what is the best way to do it? First line from 11/14 up to 12/26 and the second one from 1/2 till the end. Result which I would like to achieve below. Thank you in advance!

data frame which I used
date value
11/14/2020  18.57
11/21/2020  19.62
11/28/2020  21.81
12/5/2020   21.24
12/12/2020  22.32
12/19/2020  20.79
12/26/2020  21.18
1/2/2021    21.38
1/9/2021    21.22
1/16/2021   20.45
1/23/2021   19.11
1/30/2021   20.74

ggplot(sns1, aes(x = date, y = metric_value)) + geom_line(size = 1, color = "#E41A1C")

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **geom_segment**:

```
geom_segment(aes(x=..., y=..., xend=..., yend=...))
```

You just have to replace with the values you want your line to start and stop.

Edit: with your data, that will do something like

```
ggplot(sns1, aes(x = date, y = metric_value)) +
geom_line(size = 1, color = "#E41A1C") +
geom_segment(aes(x= 11/14/2020, y=20.6, xend=12/26/2020, yend=21.5))+
geom_segment(...)
```

With the same idea for the second line.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this idea, but do you see maybe solution with geom_smooth to get standard error overview? I would like to avoid fixed values as report is updated every week and new 'end' values are added

Comment: I don't know how to use `geom_smooth` on 2 distinct parts of a graph. But you can give the part of data you want to use as argument:
`... + geom_smooth(data=sns1[,date < 12/26], se = TRUE) + geom_smooth(data=sns1[,date > 12/26], se = TRUE)`

That might work but i'm not sure

Comment: Yes, with small modification it worked 'data = sns1[sns1$date < as.Date("2021-02-13"),])'. Thank you very much for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to not consider the cutoff date part of both trends, you can do it in a single `geom_smooth()` statement by specifying the groups.

```r
library(ggplot2)

txt <- "date value
11/14/2020 18.57
11/21/2020 19.62
11/28/2020 21.81
12/5/2020 21.24
12/12/2020 22.32
12/19/2020 20.79
12/26/2020 21.18
1/2/2021 21.38
1/9/2021 21.22
1/16/2021 20.45
1/23/2021 19.11
1/30/2021 20.74"

sns1 <- read.table(text = txt, sep = " ", header = TRUE)
sns1$date <- as.Date(sns1$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

cutoff <- as.Date("2020/12/26")

ggplot(sns1, aes(date, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = date >= cutoff),
              method = "lm")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is really great option as well, thank you very much for that!